# deciphering a sass mixin

Tags: sass

familiarizing myself with a code base for an in-progress project that I will be joining soon.  I came across this mixin being used frequently and I have a couple of questions.
1.  is this a fairly standard practice or css idiom and I am just unfamiliar with it?
2.  Looks like it's adding an empty space after the pseudo element for the clearfix, but why insert one :before also?

```
@mixin container
  &:before, &:after
  content: ""
  display: table
&:after
  clear: both
  *zoom: 1
```

Obviously I could just wait and ask the team when I join up but I want to know now dangit! Also, if it's an idiom I should be familiar with, maybe I have some googling to do before then lol. 
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the "micro clearfix" by Nicolas Gallagher (see: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).  The explanation behind the `:before` is as follows:

> This “micro clearfix” generates pseudo-elements and sets their display
>   to table. This creates an anonymous table-cell and a new block
>   formatting context that means the :before pseudo-element prevents
>   top-margin collapse. The :after pseudo-element is used to clear the
>   floats. As a result, there is no need to hide any generated content
>   and the total amount of code needed is reduced.
>
> Including the :before selector is not necessary to clear the floats,
>   but it prevents top-margins from collapsing in modern browsers.